# how to change direction of RayMenu

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, menu

How can I change the direction of the Icons expanding in the [RayMenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu)! In the current situation it is in the horizontal direction. i would like to have it in the vertical direction in my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats library cant change Raymenu into vertical direction. You should try this [library](https://github.com/BrotherV/ArcRayMenu) if you want vertical direction.